# distcp failing with error "No space left on device"

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, snapshot, distcp

I am copying HDFS snapshot to S3 bucket, getting below error:
The command i am executing is:
hadoop distcp /.snapshot/$SNAPSHOTNAME s3a://$ACCESSKEY:$SECRETKEY@$BUCKET/$SNAPSHOTNAME

```
    15/08/20 06:50:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 38% reduce 0%
15/08/20 06:50:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 39% reduce 0%
15/08/20 06:52:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 41% reduce 0%
15/08/20 06:52:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1439998402428_0006_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: File copy failed: hdfs://mycluster/.snapshot/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/tmp/hive/vladmetodiev/6da8eee9-f482-4d07-96dc-87ff77a4efe4/hive_2015-07-23_17-12-21_989_8312247652079703611-121/-ext-10001/000035_0 --> s3n://AKIAJPPHQ6RXAPWCFMAA:RVZ9Q1+ezHkUVPEbasg4BUIGAS59C27bhJiNNlgD@ul-pdc-eu/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/tmp/hive/vladmetodiev/6da8eee9-f482-4d07-96dc-87ff77a4efe4/hive_2015-07-23_17-12-21_989_8312247652079703611-121/-ext-10001/000035_0
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't run retriable-command: Copying hdfs://mycluster/.snapshot/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/tmp/hive/vladmetodiev/6da8eee9-f482-4d07-96dc-87ff77a4efe4/hive_2015-07-23_17-12-21_989_8312247652079703611-121/-ext-10001/000035_0 to s3n://AKIAJPPHQ6RXAPWCFMAA:RVZ9Q1+ezHkUVPEbasg4BUIGAS59C27bhJiNNlgD@ul-pdc-eu/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/tmp/hive/vladmetodiev/6da8eee9-f482-4d07-96dc-87ff77a4efe4/hive_2015-07-23_17-12-21_989_8312247652079703611-121/-ext-10001/000035_0
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:280)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
        at java.security.DigestOutputStream.write(DigestOutputStream.java:148)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsOutputStream.write(NativeS3FileSystem.java:293)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyBytes(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyToFile(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doCopy(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doExecute(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:87)
        ... 11 more

15/08/20 06:53:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1439998402428_0006_m_000007_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: File copy failed: hdfs://mycluster/.snapshot/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/apps/hbase/data/data/default/XXHBCL01/985fbc7692868e3315ada852bcb59e1d/tr/77c160e32bfc4175a65d6a56feaeeb6c --> s3n://AKIAJPPHQ6RXAPWCFMAA:RVZ9Q1+ezHkUVPEbasg4BUIGAS59C27bhJiNNlgD@ul-pdc-eu/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/apps/hbase/data/data/default/XXHBCL01/985fbc7692868e3315ada852bcb59e1d/tr/77c160e32bfc4175a65d6a56feaeeb6c
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't run retriable-command: Copying hdfs://mycluster/.snapshot/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/apps/hbase/data/data/default/XXHBCL01/985fbc7692868e3315ada852bcb59e1d/tr/77c160e32bfc4175a65d6a56feaeeb6c to s3n://AKIAJPPHQ6RXAPWCFMAA:RVZ9Q1+ezHkUVPEbasg4BUIGAS59C27bhJiNNlgD@ul-pdc-eu/HDFS-SNAPSHOT-PROD.08-20-2015-06-06/apps/hbase/data/data/default/XXHBCL01/985fbc7692868e3315ada852bcb59e1d/tr/77c160e32bfc4175a65d6a56feaeeb6c
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:280)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
        at java.security.DigestOutputStream.write(DigestOutputStream.java:148)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsOutputStream.write(NativeS3FileSystem.java:293)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyBytes(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyToFile(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doCopy(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doExecute(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:87)
        ... 11 more
```

However there is enough space on device aroubnt 4 TB, Please help.

Comment: what is the size of the file ?

Comment: File size is around 350 GB.

Comment: Unfortunately, distcp tries to stage the data you're uploading to S3 on a local directory first. That local directly is filling up, yielding the error you're seeing. [This tip](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/disk-space-issue-on-nodes-for-distcp-data-transfer-from-hdfs-to/m-p/26475/highlight/true#M1153) will help you specify an alternate directory for distcp to use to stage the data before uploading.

Answer (score 2):

So I ran into this same problem and here is the what ultimately worked for me:

hadoop distcp -D mapreduce.job.maxtaskfailures.per.tracker=1 ...

I tried a few things (with the help of a colleagues) but the main thing that worked for me was - 
Changed max task failures per tracker to 1. This is mostly the key. Basically individual nodes were running out of space. So by doing this I am forcing the job not to retry on a node once it has failed on it already.

Other things that I tried but didn't work
1. Increase number of mappers. (-m )
2. Increased the number of retries from 3 to 12. 
(-D yarn.app.mapreduce.client.max-retries=12)